# VBA ADO connection to .xlsx file

Tags: vba, excel-2007, ado

I am trying to copy data from a closed Excel 2007 workbook (.xlsx) using an ADO connection.

I have the connection string working.  But I get an automation error when I try to open the Command in the Recordset (Second to last line).

This may not be clear in the below code so:

"wsSummary" is a worksheet object
"strSourceFile" is a string with the target data I need to copy from (e.g. Template.xlsx)

```
strSourceFile = wsSummary.Cells(nFirstRow + 4, 7)
strSheetSource = "Sheet1"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheetSource & "]"

Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
With dbConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .connectionString = "Data Source=" & strPOINTDataPath & strSourceFile & _
                        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    .ConnectionTimeout = 40
    .Open
End With
If dbConnection = "" Then GoTo ErrorText

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
    .CommandText = strSQL
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open cmd
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed `$ character` in your SQL statement. Try to change appropriate line into this one:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheetSource & "$]"
```

or change `strSheetSource variable` into this:

```
strSheetSource = "Sheet1$"
```