# Excel .xlsx VBA ADODB connection error when opening file from sharepoint

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, adodb

I am trying to read a file from sharepoint location. The code works absolutely fine when reading from local drive. 
Please also note that the file type is .xlsx
If I convert the file into .xls the code works fine regardless whether the file is on the server or on the local path.

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & dataPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
```

#### Error received

> External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: may be the connection string. check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144838/vba-ado-connection-to-xlsx-file#18144945

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for the response. I don't think connection string has a problem as I am able to connect but somehow the table doesn't seem to be read properly. What I expect is that I might be missing a parameter which I need to specify. Notice that I am using "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" and not the other provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0".

Comment: i faintly remember that i had something like this years ago. it was some parameter like HDR.  i remember this site https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: it may have been this `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";"`

Comment: or this ... the xml keyword rings a bell   `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting directly to sharepoint server to access a file creates a lot of problems.

### For Example

- 1 of the issue is already described above;
- 2 issue is that you would have to manually connect to sharepoint everytime the computer starts before the program can read the file.

A better way of connection can be found in the following answer:

[Get the content of a sharepoint folder with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)